# R: efficient way to find out variable type

Tags: r

What is the best way to find out the data type of variable "ypred" generated from the following code (the last line)? I know class(ypred) is "factor", but this is not what I want...

```
library(e1017)
data(iris)
iris2 = iris[(iris$Species == 'setosa') | (iris$Species == 'virginica'),]
train = iris2[c(1:25, 51:75),]
test = iris2[c(26:50, 76:nrow(iris2)),]
m = svm(Species~., data=train, type = "nu-classification", kernel = "radial", probability = TRUE)
ypred = predict(m, test, probability = TRUE)
```

I've tried the following:

```
> is.matrix(ypred)
[1] FALSE
> is.list(ypred)
[1] FALSE
> is.array(ypred)
[1] FALSE
> is.data.frame(ypred)
[1] FALSE
> is.vector(ypred)
[1] FALSE
```

I know that attributes(ypred) is a nice R list, but I'm still confused with

- the data type of "ypred" itself.
- how do I know I can apply the function "attributes", before digging into the documentation?

I'm a beginner of R and I appreciate if you can give some advice on how to figure out data type / data structure in R that is beyond the atomic numeric, integer, logical, character and complex

Comment: `typeof()` ?     is that it ?

Comment: No, it says it's "integer" -- which is not what I'm looking for. Thank you though.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `str(ypred)`, which tells you it's a factor with several additional attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Use `class`,

```
data(iris)
iris2 <- iris[(iris$Species == 'setosa') | (iris$Species == 'virginica'),]
train <- iris2[c(1:25, 51:75),]
test <- iris2[c(26:50, 76:nrow(iris2)),]
require(e1071)
m <- svm(Species~., data=train, type = "nu-classification", kernel = "radial", probability = TRUE)
ypred <- predict(m, test, probability = TRUE)
class(iris2)
# [1] "data.frame"
class(train)
# [1] "data.frame"
class(test)
# [1] "data.frame"
class(m)
# [1] "svm.formula" "svm"        
class(ypred)
# [1] "factor"
```

I would use `<-` for assignments instead of `=` to prevent variables being assigned to your global environment.

Answer (score 2):

The data type is `integer`, but the class is `factor`. Factors are represented by integers internally, and printed as character. For more see `?factor`

The way you can tell what type of object this is and that you'd need attributes function is by checking under where it says "VALUE" in `?predict`. Here it says to check the specific predict function for the object you're predicting (svm), so type:

```
?predict.svm
```

It tells you under VALUE that it will return a vector of predicted values with a "probabilities" attribute.

Comment: Thank you. I was not familiar with having attributes with a vector, but it makes sense now.

Comment: Another question, why it says "false" when I try "is.vector(ypred)" as in the original post?

Comment: got you, thank you. "is.vector returns TRUE if x is a vector of the specified mode having no attributes other than names. It returns FALSE otherwise." this is very clear.